# Partition mounted noexec even though not specified in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, partition, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 12. There I have several partitions which I auto-mount on startup. *pysdm* says that */dev/sda6* should permit execution of binaries. Also the */etc/fstab* says it should.

```
/dev/sda7   /media/Data         btrfs  users,user           0  0
/dev/sda8   /media/LocalBackup  btrfs  users,user           0  0
```

But executing scripts that are on this said partition yield *"Permission denied"*. Also `mount` says "noexec", even though that's not specified neither in fstab nor pysdm.

```
/dev/sda7 on /media/Data type btrfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda8 on /media/LocalBackup type btrfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

Where is the error? Is there a further file that influences partition mounting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that, as a security feature, anything with `user` in the fstab is automatically mounted `noexec` unless `exec` is explicitly given in the fstab.

Comment: I deleted both `user` and `users` from the fstab, now it is only mounted `rw`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using the 'Disks' tool on Ubuntu (via the GUI) and was able to simply add the `exec` option. That seems to of prevented the `noexec` which `user` option adds.

Answer (score 1):

Using the option user and mounting with root privileges, will add options such as noexec, nosuid and nodev.

Mounting as a regular user, everything is fine.

So, either remove user or add the option noauto. Also, you can append the options  exec and suid to a user. however, this is not recommended for security reasons.

**user**
Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem. The name of the mounting user is written to the mtab file (or to the private libmount file in /run/mount on systems without a regular mtab), so that this same user can unmount the filesystem again. This option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line user,exec,dev,suid).

**noauto**
Can only be mounted explicitly (i.e., the -a option will not cause the filesystem to be mounted).

more details can be found in [man mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)