# 'exec' option ignored in fstab for sshfs, need to specify to 'mount' on command-line?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, sshfs

I'm using sshfs in my fstab to mount a filesystem in Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS:

```
sshfs#dave@myservergoeshere.com:/remote-dir /mnt/local-mnt  fuse    rw,exec,user,allow_other,noauto,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3  0 0
```

It mounts fine, but if I try to execute anything in the path I get:

```
./some-executable: Permission denied.
```

The file has execute permissions (and works fine if I am actually ssh'd into the system).

If I use the fstab but include the -oexec option again:

```
mount /mnt/local-mnt -oexec
```

Then it works.  Why is the fstab 'exec' being ignored?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `exec` option is not being ignored - it's being overwritten by an implicit `noexec` associated with the subsequent `user` option. This behavior is alluded to in `man mount`:

> ```
>    user   Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the
>           mounting user is written to the mtab file  (or  to  the  private
>           libmount  file  in /run/mount on systems without a regular mtab)
>           so that this same user can unmount the filesystem  again.   This
>           option  implies  the  options  noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless
>           overridden  by  subsequent  options,  as  in  the  option   line
>           user,exec,dev,suid).
> ```

You can get the desired behavior by specifying the `exec` option after the `user` option.

See also

- [Partition mounted noexec even though not specified in /etc/fstab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37980/partition-mounted-noexec-even-though-not-specified-in-etc-fstab)