# permission denied even as root

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, root

```
❯ ./my-project
zsh: permission denied: ./my-project
```

I just make a partition out of my hard drive (not the same drive with root) with type ext4 so i think it should be fine using it on my linux.

```
# /etc/fstab for the said partition
# /dev/sdb1
UUID=36dc4434-119a-4feb-9fae-adeb9e449282   /mnt/hdp1   ext4    defaults,exec,user  0 0
```

Recently i tried to make a rust project and run it inside the new partition, but when i run it

```
❯ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.18s
     Running `target/debug/my-project
error: could not execute process `target/debug/my-project` (never executed)

Caused by:
  Permission denied (os error 13)
```

i thought it's because the cargo permission or something, so i look it up for similar problem, but nothing works for me.

and then i tried run the file directly and

```
❯ ./my-project
zsh: permission denied: ./my-project
```

and then i look for permission and stuff, i even make the entire content of the drive owned by `me` as user, set mod for all file and dir to be

```
drwxr-xr-x
-rwxr-xr-x
```

(also chmod 777 at some point)

but nothing works.
i even try to run it as root

```
❯ su
Password:
[root@laptop debug]# ./my-project
bash: ./my-project: Permission denied
```

Maybe i haven't research hard enough, i don't know.
At this point i don't care, because it bothers me so much.

You can blame me for anything, for now i need the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: This may be relevant: ['exec' option ignored in fstab for sshfs, need to specify to 'mount' on command-line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590543/exec-option-ignored-in-fstab-for-sshfs-need-to-specify-to-mount-on-command)

Comment: ok right that's a duplicate.

Comment: @steeldriver thank you!

Comment: @A.B it does! i never thought the problem was because the order of the options