# Unable to exec programs, parent directory symbolic link, btrfs mdadm drive

Tags: permissions, executable

I'm not sure what to try next to resolve this issue.

```
~  cat /etc/fstab
# /dev/sdg1  /mnt/d/  ntfs    noatime,nodiratime,users,noauto,x-systemd.automount,autodefrag   0 0
/dev/md127   /mnt/d   btrfs   nofail,compress=zstd:1,noatime,nodiratime,users                  0 0
```

The disk mount location `/mnt/d` was previously used by an ntfs drive but not sure how relevant that is since I've rebooted already

```
~  chmod +x ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
~  ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
fish: The file “./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh” is not executable by this user
```

```
~  ls -lah ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
Permissions Size User Date Modified Name
.rwxr-xr-x@  977 xk   10 Jan 14:00  ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh*
~  lsattr ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
---------------------- ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
~  file ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
~  ldd ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh'
    not a dynamic executable
```

```
~ [1]  ls /mnt
Permissions Size User Date Modified Name
drwxr-xr-x     - xk    5 Mar 00:18  d/
~  ls | grep 'd ->'
lrwxrwxrwx     7 xk   28 Feb 22:30  d -> /mnt/d/
~  ls | grep bin
lrwxrwxrwx@   23 xk    5 Mar 00:13  bin -> d/35_Linux_Software/bin/
```

```
~  uid
1000
~  ls -n ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh
Permissions Size User Date Modified Name
.rwxr-xr-x@  977 1000 10 Jan 14:00  ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/install.sh*
```

I can read files just fine

```
~  head -1 ./bin/SoulseekQt-2018-1-30-64bit.AppImage
ELFAI> !@@s@@@@@@@@@@dd ddada` @e@ea@e@@DDPtd00A0A

                                                Qtd/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNU...
```

When making the loader explicit things run fine:

```
~  cd ./bin/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64/
~/b/DownZemAll_v2.5.5_x86_64  bash install.sh
Copying Manifest.JSON to Mozilla directory...
```

Not sure why it says "ELF file ABI version invalid" but I would prefer if I could exec like a normal unix person (okay that is an [AppImage related thing](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageSpec/issues/15) and not relevant to my problem)

```
~  file bin/SoulseekQt-2018-1-30-64bit.AppImage
bin/SoulseekQt-2018-1-30-64bit.AppImage: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=d4b0eeecada37bbc753023885a3f0f7e3bdac6cc, stripped
~  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./bin/SoulseekQt-2018-1-30-64bit.AppImage
./bin/SoulseekQt-2018-1-30-64bit.AppImage: error while loading shared libraries: ./bin/SoulseekQt-2018-1-30-64bit.AppImage: ELF file ABI version invalid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this:

[Partition mounted noexec even though not specified in /etc/fstab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37980/partition-mounted-noexec-even-though-not-specified-in-etc-fstab)

I should've looked at the output of the command `mount` instead of fstab